# How to keep excel formatting when copypasting from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, formatting, ms-office, excel-2010

In our test team we still stick to good old excel as our testcase management (creator) tool

And every time, when creating new testcase, this happens to me:
[image: above new one down old one]

When creating new testcase, the row width always stays the same and I have to manually to uodate the width manually. Is there better way to do it?

BTW, yes, I could store empty testcase somewhere and use it when doing new one, but it **always** happens that someone in our team presses "Save" instead of "Save as..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using an Excel Template File? (extension is xltx).

Normally when you open this file it creates a new file based on the template. You really have to right-click it and select "open" instead of the default "new" to edit the template file itself.

Kind regards,
Wim

Comment: DUH! Do you ever have feeling that you don’t see the most easy answers because you are just over-thinking everything? This helped. Thanks a lot!